# I got these errors in my flutter app whenever I start to call API request. It take me a long time to find the error. But I can't still find this

Tags: flutter, api, http

```
 import 'dart:convert';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    //calling back the request function for data.
    super.initState();
  }

  getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021-06-19&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=aef6cc5fa8bb4554a1d76e614b4b5952"));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    //change to json type data
    print(jsonData);
  }
```

Here is the error I got when I try to request data from API :

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsriv.png)

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
      @override
void didChangeDependencies() {
    getData();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

instead of

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    //calling back the request function for data.
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks u. I tried it but it still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.
I mistyped some unnecessary characters in built-in flutter io.dart file.
And sorry for my mistakes.